# get .html AND the container

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/jquery-get-selected-elements-outer-html)

so I have a div..

```
<div id="fred">
```

it has stuff in it

```
<div id="fred">
  <tr id="thing1">hello1</tr>
  <tr id="thing2">hello2</tr>
</div>
```

if I call

```
$("#fred").html();
```

I get just the items inside:

```
  <tr id="thing1">hello1</tr>
  <tr id="thing2">hello2</tr>
```

I want the whole thing:

```
<div id="fred">
  <tr id="thing1">hello1</tr>
  <tr id="thing2">hello2</tr>
</div>
```

I know that I can ref using this[0], but it seems like there should be an easier way..

I tried `.andSelf()` but apparently that doesn't do what I thought it should doo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/jquery-get-selected-elements-outer-html)

EDIT: I'll elaborate...

This plugin does the job:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
return (s)
? this.before(s).remove()
: jQuery("&lt;p&gt;").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
```

you can then simply call:

```
$('#myTag').outerHTML()
```

Comment: Pointing to someone else's answer isn't really an answer in itself...

Comment: this seems to be an IE only solution..

Comment: Okay, should have put it in the comment I guess.  This it not IE only and the edit to my answer is not valid, newish here, I will edit if possible.

Comment: @lonesomeday Maybe we should leave answers in comments then, so the question never gets answered... then we have a bunch of unanswered questions, because we can't mark a question as a solution. Pointing to someone else's answer IS an answer. Otherwise, you could *never* answer a question. period.

Comment: with all due respect, kingjiv, cross-browser is why you use JQuery

Comment: this solution is NOT IE only.  The outerhtml property is IE only, this is a jQuery equivilent that is cross-browser.

Comment: @xixonia If you're going to point to another person's answer, put it in a comment -- it's not fair to earn rep for someone else's answer.

Comment: That's no inefficient and nasty and slow... If you're cloning nodes, at least do it natively and not using a thick jQuery layer.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't support `outerHTML`: http://api.jquery.com/html/#comment-84945158

(`.andSelf` is for element sets, not for depth.)

I think the best solution would be `el[0].outerHTML` (no extra 'plugin' required and native JS s always good)

Comment: `outerHTML` isn't cross-browser.

Comment: It's not??? Oops =) I've been using that for ages... **edit** Both Chrome 11 and IE 8 know it...

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/9NaZU/

Comment: And, say, Firefox? `outerHTML` is not standards compliant, and it's not supported in a fair proportion of your userbase's browsers.

Comment: Firefox? What's that? (Good point. I give up.) (LOL @ "standards compliant". Whose standards? The W3C that's always behind 3 years?)